# How can I make this repeating code look neater

Tags: c

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm on a constrained platform so I'm trying to use as little additional variables as possible.

```
...
switch (var->type) {
    case (something1):
        if (var->x >= 100 && var->x <= 105) {
            do_something(var);
            return;
        }
        break;

    case (something2):
        if (var->x >= 150 && var->x <= 155) {
            do_something(var);
            return;
        }
        break;

    case (something3):
        if (var->y >= 80 && var->y <= 85) {
            do_something(var);
            return;
        }
        break;

    case (something4):
        if (var->y >= 120 && var->y <= 125) {
            do_something(var);
            return;
        }
        break;
}
...
```

Basically the code just checks the type of the variable, checks range on an axis specific to that type, and calls a function if the condition is met, does nothing if not. `do_something()` is the exact same function within all of the `if` segments.

I'm sure there's an easy way to write this with less repetition, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What values can `type` contain? You could create an array holding the limits for each case if the values are not too large and don't contain too large gaps. Then you might take the `type` as index into that array. Or you could just set some boolean variable to indicate whether you have to perform the action or not and do it once after all the tests instead of doing it again and again.

Comment: This is a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Instead of `var->type` you could have `var->min` and `var->max` and then have `if (var->y >= var->min && var->y <= var->max) do_something(var);`

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for the suggestion! I forgot to mention that this code is for a constrained platform with limited resources, so I'm trying to use as little additional variables as possible. I'll edit the question to mention that.

Comment: @Cid I didn't know about this site. I'll delete this question and post it over there, thank you.

Comment: If the values are small and without gaps, an array holding limits that is checked with a small loop might take less memory than checking all these cases.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'll look into it. I'll do some testing to figure out what runs faster in my case, thanks for the input again!

Comment: @Cid when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Comment: Regarding your comment *" I'm on a constrained platform so I'm trying to use as little additional variables as possible."* here's something very important to understand for you: __The amount of variables in your code has *zero* relationship to the amount of resources consumed!__ If you want to get into the nitty-gritty details, you should look into the concept of ["Static Single Assignment Forms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form). The cliff notes version is, that "variables" are just names used by the compiler to track the flow of data, nothing more.

Comment: @datenwolf I will read up on this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
switch (var->type) {
case (something1):
    if (! (var->x >= 100 && var->x <= 105)) return;
    break;
case (something2):
    if (! (var->x >= 150 && var->x <= 155)) return;
    break;
case (something3):
    if (! (var->y >= 80 && var->y <= 85)) return;
    break;
case (something4):
    if (! (var->y >= 120 && var->y <= 125)) return;
    break;
default:
    return;
}
do_something();
```

Comment: Love this, thank you. Somebody pointed out that a question like this belongs to CodeReview, not here. I'll accept this as an answer and then delete the question. Hopefully it'll let you keep your point.

Comment: If I do, then the OP does, because they do the same thing: do_something() is called if and only if the variable is in the range determined by the type.

Comment: Thanks, but always wait a while before accepting an answer to give others a chance to do better.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct { int type; int y;} var[] = { 3, 82 };
    struct range { int min; int max; } range;

    switch(var->type) {
    case 1: range = (struct range){100,105}; break;
    case 2: range = (struct range){150,155}; break;
    case 3: range = (struct range){80,85}; break;
    case 4: range = (struct range){120,125}; break;
    }

    if( var->y >= range.min && var->y <= range.max) {
        do_something();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the `somethingN` are sufficiently small enough integers, this can generalize nicely to something like:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct { int type; int y;} var[] = { 3, 82 };
    struct range { int min; int max; } range[] = {
        {0,0},
        {100,105},
        {150,155},
        {80,85},
        {120,125},
    };


    if( var->y >= range[var->type].min && var->y <= range[var->type].max) {
        do_something();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this approach fails to notice that the comparisons are sometimes for member `x`, and sometimes for `y`.  That can be addressed with something like:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct { int type; int x, y;} var[] = { 3, 81, 82 };
    struct range { int *v; int min; int max; } range[] = {
        {&var->x, 0,0},
        {&var->x, 100,105},
        {&var->x, 150,155},
        {&var->y, 80,85},
        {&var->y, 120,125},
    };

    int c = *(range[var->type].v);
    if( c >= range[var->type].min && c <= range[var->type].max) {
        do_something();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't notice that some of the ranges are checking x and some y.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That's easy enough to fix.  Will edit.

Comment: Hi, this also is a nice looking solution, but it would most likely be slower than the accepted answer on my target platform. I've edited the question with the constrains and apologise for not mentioning them earlier. Upvoting this answer regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```c
typedef enum {
 something1,
 something2,
 something3,
 something4,
 sometype_max
} some_type;

struct {
 int min;
 int max;
} limits[] = 
{
  [something1] = {100, 105},
  [something2] = {150, 155},
  [something3] = {80, 85},
  [something4] = {120, 125}
};

...

if (var->type < sometype_max)
{
  if ((var->x > limits[var->type].min) && (var->x < limits[var->type].max))
  {
    do_something();
  }    
}
```

Comment: I like this, but as I mentioned, I'm positive this could would be a little bit slower than the accepted answer on my target platform. Sorry for not mentioning the constrains right away! I'm upvoting the answer regardless.